# Will the change in App Password authentication affect existing REST API authentication?

Tags: docusignapi

DocuSign is introducing App Password authentication, a new way to authenticate via the SOAP API. Will this have any effect on existing  REST APIs authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are referring to.

Are you authenticating with the REST APIs using OAuth2?(JWT or Authorisation Code Grant flows) or are you using the old basic authentication using the `X-DocuSign-Authentication` header?

If it is the former, then you will be fine but if you are using the latter method, then that will be deprecated as per [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/october-2022-oauth2-required&ved=2ahUKEwiHkKO49_D4AhUTumMGHRvgDpMQFnoECA4QAQ&usg=AOvVaw0TF8RLbo-a2ejreHZwrlfs)

Answer (score 0):

App Passwords are for the eSign SOAP API (which does not support OAuth).

App Passwords can be used with eSign REST API apps until you upgrade them to OAuth. You `must` plan to upgrade your eSign REST API apps to OAuth.